# Array Elements continously appended

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im querying from firebase and elements are returning properly. However when I search for something twice two elements appear. Which means two elements were appended to the array. Should be one and only one the thing that comes back from search. Two elements should not be there if I search twice.

```
 if self.postsArray.count == 0
           {
               self.postsArray.append(newPost!)


               self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                   return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

               }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
               }

           }
           else
           {

               for post in self.postsArray
               {
                   if post.key == newPost?.key{

                       self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
                       }
                       return
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       self.postsArray.append(newPost!)
                       //                            self.postsArray.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                       //                                return post1.title.compare(post2.title) == .orderedAscending
                       //                            })

                       self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
                       }

                   }

               }

           }
```

So Im asking nicely if someone could look at this and see where the error in my logic is that is making things be added to the filtered events array more than once

Comment: I guess problem is in for loop , there whenever a new post is not equal you are appending the new post to the array, whereas it should only be appended once, so if array contains 10 elements and new post is not equal to any one of these, then new post would be appended 10 times

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that actually but how do I fix that. I only want it to append if it doesn't exist

Comment: @user1000 see comments

Comment: Check my answer, see if it helps, if you face problem please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess problem is in for loop , there whenever a new post is not equal you are appending the new post to the array, whereas it should only be appended once

So you can use filter to see if it contains newPost

so replace

```
for post in self.postsArray
               {
                   if post.key == newPost?.key{

                       self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
                       }
                       return
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       self.postsArray.append(newPost!)
                       //                            self.postsArray.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                       //                                return post1.title.compare(post2.title) == .orderedAscending
                       //                            })

                       self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
                       }

                   }
```

with

```
let filteredArr = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.key == newPost?.key
}

if filteredArr.count == 0 {
     //append
     self.postsArray.append(newPost!)
} 


 self.filteredPosts = self.postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
                           return post.title.lowercased().contains(stringValue.lowercased())

                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.exploreCollectionView?.reloadData()
                       }
```

Comment: I love you bro been at this for hours

Comment: @RyanGosling No worries, glad I could help

Comment: what happens if my count is not always going to be zero

Comment: see comments please

Comment: @RyanGosling Then it means that your newPost is already there, so you dont need to apped it , and your data will stay same

Comment: okay let me rephrase the question what If I have similar array elements. Let's say I have two elements containing the number 1 I want to return both of them not one of them.

Comment: see comments again please

Comment: @RyanGosling I think this is a different question, you should ask another question so others can help you also, please ask another question and provide details , I will try to help you there

Comment: I can't I have to wait 40 mins @user1000